# системная переменная в Visual Studio

Tags: c++17

Я создал системную переменную для библиотеки `%INCLUDE%` и хочу ее использовать так:

```
#include <%INCLUDE%/MyHpp.h>
```

как это можно сделать в Visual Studio?

Comment: А почему бы компилятору не передать путь поиска заголовочных файлов стандартным способом (как флаг компиляции `-I` или как это в студии принято делать). P.S. в данном случае, наверное, правильнее использовать кавычки.

Comment: Меня и интересует именно использование системных переменных. Полный путь я могу задать и в настройках проекта.

Comment: А что Вы хотите сделать? похоже Вы решаете XY-проблему

Comment: На многих других языках я добавляю папку в стандартный путь поиска, а в С++ не получается. Например в Python это выглядит так - conda develop "C:/Users/Wlad/.myPython"

Comment: conda - это не "другие языки". это одна с многих утилит для установки пакетов. Похоже Вы ищите [VcPkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.md) или что то подобное.

Comment: Я ищу способ добавить мою папку в стандартный путь поиска, чтобы я мог использовать угловые скобки.

Comment: раньше так можно было - в студии была возможность прям свои каталоги добавить. Теперь предлагают использовать props файлы и просто подключать к своему проекту.

Comment: Есть конечно возможность создать шаблон на основе проекта, но это не совсем то, что я хочу.